# Same Path for 3 Tab in TabbledShowLayout - ReactAdmin

Tags: layout, react-admin

As the question, I have 3 tabs, in Big Tab

[image: nested TabbedShowLayout]

the tab 01 is working perfectly fine, but the tab02, tab03 is added the /1 /2 in URL
so it's cant render anything

the Tab01 [image]

The Tab02 [image]

The Tab03[image]

I want it's not extra anything , just property/1/show is good for me.
How can I do that ? 
Or if I want to pass all data from Big Tab (property/1/show) to tab01,02,03 how can I do that ?